# how to implement dynamic autoupdate of title bar in vue?

Tags: html, css, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I am very new to web dev and i am trying to resolve this issue from quite some time, please help me with this,
I have implemented a series of verticle slides each slide contains 10 images and every time i reach bottom i call next images from api call. now i wish to print no. of slide i am presently active on I used below code for it but this way on going to top or below value of slide no. increments and finally becomes constant.

```
<div class="left">
       {{slideno}} 
       
      </div>    
     
  <div v-for="(images, index) in slides"
                  :key="index" >{{setslideNumber(index)}}


      <div class="container read">
        <div
          class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 reader-section"
        >
          <div
            id="carousel-pager"
            class="carousel slide "
            data-ride="carousel"
            data-interval="1000"
          >
            <div class="carousel-inner vertical">
              <div class=" item" style="object-fit: fill;">
              <div 
                  v-for="(image, index) in images"
                  :key="index"
                  class="section"
                  style="color:#fff"
                >
                  <img
                    :src="
                      image
                    "
                    class="img-responsive"
                    data-target="#carousel-main"
                    data-slide-to="0"
                    width:100
                  />
                </div>
                 <div v-if="images.length" v-observe-visibility="handleScrolledToBottom"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a
              class="left carousel-control"
              href="#carousel-pager"
              role="button"
              data-slide="prev"
            >
              <span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a
              class="right carousel-control"
              href="#carousel-pager"
              role="button"
              data-slide="next"
            >
              <span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
```

```
 methods: {
setSlideNumber(index){
      this.slideno=index+1;
    },
}
```

what value of sliden0 i am getting: 123....10
what i need the value of slide that is visible,

Comment: Try this.slideno = +index + 1;

Comment: what if i am going upward index should decrease right,

and why to add slideno + sliden0(i.e index+1)?\